# Is the OLEDB provider managed or unmanaged?

Tags: .net, sql-server

Is the OLEDB provider managed or unmanaged?

Comment: huh? Sorry, but could you please rephrase your question? Like this it is hardly understandable what you want to know.

Answer (score 3):

OLEDB as the name suggests is implemented and accessed using OLE or COM. It is an unmanaged technology, but you can use it via COM/interop in the usual fashion.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I am aware, the answer is *both*.

The ADO.NET part is managed (`System.Data.OleDb`), but the underlying OLEDB driver will be native.

Comment: Actually, strictly speaking System.Data.OleDb is an OLEDB Client, not a provider. I'm unaware of any provider implemented in managed code but it's theoretically possible w/ COM Interop.